# Get percentage of increase/decrease from two results base on their WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I don't know if my Title is understandable but what I am really trying to achieve is get the percentage increase/decrease of Result 2 from Result 1.

I have a SALES table with these sample data:

```
DATE.         AMOUNT
01-JAN-20.    500
02-JAN-20.    400
...
15-MAR-20.    1000
```

Assume that the table is filled with daily sales.

Now, with the Dashboard app I'm trying to make in APEX, I want to display the TOTAL AMOUNT base from the DATE the user will choose on a SELECT list (Today, This Week, This Month).
So basically, these would be the queries:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTAL_SALES FROM TB_SALES WHERE DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE); - Today

SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTAL_SALES FROM TB_SALES WHERE DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-7,'SUNDAY') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE); - This Week

SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTAL_SALES FROM TB_SALES WHERE DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM' AND TRUNC(SYSDATE); - This Month
```

To get the percentage of increase or decrease, I now then need to get the result of same queries but different DATE from the WHERE clause.

So with Yesterday, I should query 
`TRUNC(SYSDATE -1);` 
And so on. Actually I still don't know how to get the This week part.

With the two results, I can now calculate the percentage.

What I can't figure out is how can I query this two WHERE clause of two DATEs. My current temporary solution is to query the second query and just use JavaScript to update my Card.

I found something about LAG functions but cannot find any sample which uses WHERE clause to compare the results.

EDIT:
To be more clear, this is what I want to compare and get the percentage.

```
Today VS Yesterday
This week VS Last week
This month VS Last month
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to find the totals:

```sql
SELECT SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
         AND  "DATE" <=  SYSDATE
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_today,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
         AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_yesterday,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
         AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_this_week,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '14' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
         AND  "DATE" <  NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_last_week,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ),
         AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_this_iso_week,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_last_iso_week,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '6' DAY,
         AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_this_7_days,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '13' DAY,
         AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '6' DAY
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_last_7_days,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_this_month
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN "DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
         AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total_this_month
FROM   tb_sales
WHERE  "DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
AND   "DATE"  <= SYSDATE;
```

This will find the totals for:

- Today and yesterday;
- This week and last week (starting from midnight Sunday until before the midnight of the next Sunday or until this instant, whichever is earlier);
- This ISO 8601 week and last ISO 8601 week (starting midnight Monday);
- The last 7 days (today and the previous 6 days) and 7 days before that; and
- This month and last month (from midnight of the first day of the month until this instant).

If you want the percentage increases compared to a previous period then:

```sql
SELECT 100 * ( total_this_today / total_yesterday - 1 ) AS percent_increase_this_today,
       100 * ( total_this_week / total_last_week - 1 ) AS percent_increase_this_week,
       100 * ( total_this_iso_week / total_last_iso_week - 1 ) AS percent_increase_this_iso_week,
       100 * ( total_this_7_days / total_last_7_days - 1 ) AS percent_increase_this_7_days,
       100 * ( total_this_month / total_last_month - 1 ) AS percent_increase_this_month
FROM   (
  SELECT SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
           AND  "DATE" <=  SYSDATE
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_today,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
           AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_yesterday,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
           AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_this_week,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '14' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
           AND  "DATE" <  NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY' )
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_last_week,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ),
           AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_this_iso_week,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY,
           AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_last_iso_week,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '6' DAY,
           AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_this_7_days,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '13' DAY,
           AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '6' DAY
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_last_7_days,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
           AND  "DATE" <= SYSDATE
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_this_month
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN "DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
           AND  "DATE" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
           THEN AMOUNT
           ELSE NULL
           END
         ) AS total_this_month
  FROM   tb_sales
  WHERE  "DATE" >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 )
  AND   "DATE"  <= SYSDATE
)
```

Comment: Hi @MTO. I think my question was not really clear and was confusing.
Basically what I want to compare and get the percentage of increase/decrease is ...
`Today VS Yesterday`

`This week (first day of week up to sysdate) VS Last week (still arguing if the whole last week or first day of last week until how many days base on the current day of current week)`

`This month VS Last month (same argument with the Week)`

I hope this is clearer.